# My Span goes behind my divs on a hover event

Tags: css, hover

First, sorry for my english, I'll try to be as clear as possible.
I've tried many things and took a look at some questions related to my problem but I can't solve it...

I've made a title with an acronym and I want to explain it when the user put the mouse over it. That's why I use a hover event but my issue is the following : I can't get the span created by the hover on the top of everything, it always goes behind my other elements despite a : `position:absolute`.

Here is my code if someone want to take a look :

```css
a{
   color:#FFFFFF;
}

a:hover, a:focus{
   background:rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.4);
}

a span{
   position:absolute;
   margin-top:50px;
   margin-left:-30px;
   color:#FFFFFF;
   background:rgba(30,144,255,.9);
   padding:15px;
   border-radius:3px;
   box-shadow:0 0 2px rgba(30,144,255,.5);
   transform:scale(0) rotate(-12deg);
   transition:all .25s;
   opacity:0;
}

a:hover span, a:focus span{
   transform:scale(1) rotate(0);
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><h1 id="mainTitle" class="text-center">Bienvenue dans <a href="#">YETI<span>Your Efficient Technical Item</span></a> Finder</h1></div>
```

Thanks for your help !
Corentin.

Comment: Have you tried setting a z index on the span?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want. When I hover over YETI, the span appears but it's below the heading, not behind it.

Comment: Awesome it works perfectly, didn't know this z-index property existed, thanks a lot @nomistic !

Comment: If you like it, check the answer below :)

Comment: Yes @j08691 you're right but it's just a tiny part of my page, I couldn't put all my code in my post ;)

Comment: fyi: your English is better than many native speakers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  It may bring it forward on the hover

```
a:hover span, a:focus span{
    transform:scale(1) rotate(0);
    opacity:1;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

you may need to put the `z-index` on the span itself.

here's a reference for this:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp